# Combining every two column values in file

Tags: shell, sed, awk, columns

I have a file with (with only one line) with multiple columns say 4 (in this case) :

```
A B C D
```

And I want the output as every possible combination of column values taking 2 at a time like:

```
AB 
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD
```

where `AB` and `BA` are equivalent. I have tried the code: `sed 's! \([^ ]\+\)\( \|$\)!\1 !g' <file_name>` but it gives the output as `AB CD`.

Please suggest how to do this using `awk` or any shell command.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? How did it fail? Do you only have one line in your input file? Is `AB` the same as `BA`? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: its like C (4,2) : taking 2 at a time out of total of 4 values. Combination of every possible 2 values with AB and BA being same result

Comment: I have tried this :  sed 's! \([^ ]\+\)\( \|$\)!\1 !g' <file> ,, but it gives output as AB CD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++){print $i$j;}}}' file
```

It's two nested `for` loops:

- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` loop trough all fields

  - `for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++)` then for each field, loop trough all remaining fields (start at `i+1`)
  - `print $i$j` print both field values.

The output:

```
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD
```